# Parsing Excel file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

1)I want to parse Excel file, which i'll receive through safari in my application. How i'll do it?

2)How can i read excel file and output its output to command prompt programmatically?

3) How can i convert excel file to .csv file programmatically?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide evidence that you've *at least* attempted to research this before asking? We're here to help with specific questions, not to research on your behalf and write the code for you. You should also take some time to accept the answers of the other questions you've asked before posting new ones.

Answer (score 2):

1) In order to parse the file from Safari you'd need to register first to be able to open XLS files. You have to add this information to your info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Microsoft Excel</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet</string>
                <string>com.microsoft.excel.xls</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Once your app is registered, the user will be able to see an "Open in ..." option while seeing the XLS file in Safari. This will launch either:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

or

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
```

Depending on if your application is in memory or not.

2) I created [QZXLSReader.](https://github.com/QuetzalMX/QuetzalXLSReader) It's a drag-and-drop solution so it's very easy to use. I don't think it's as feature complete, but it worked for me.

It's basically a library that can open XLS files and parse them into Obj-C classes. Once you have the classes, it's very easy to send them to Core Data or a dictionary or what have you.

3) Once you have opened the file with QZXLS reader, you can simply export it to a CSV file. Just iterating through all the rows and saving them to a txt file would be enough. From there, you can email, send in a message or do whatever you want with that txt file.

Comment: I tried it using. It was working awesome for reading numbers. But it is giving error in reading the strings. In case of strings it is reading special characters. Can somebody tell  me a tweak to resolve this error.